Integrating iOS Swift Screen into Compose Multiplatform Project
I'm currently working on integrating an iOS Swift screen into a Compose Multiplatform project.
Does anyone have experience with this or any tips on the best approach to achieve it?
I need to invoke a Swift UI screen from the iOS-specific part of a Kotlin Composable.
Any code examples or references would be greatly appreciated!

Some links: https://github.com/touchlab/compose-swift-bridge, https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7OIe8U2VVkA

Thanks @KevinGalligan i'll check this out.
